# How to install a downloaded deb file

Tags: software-installation, apt

I am new to Ubuntu and I am trying to install Compiz-Config-Manager, but it will not let me.
This computer is not connected to the Internet, so I downloaded the .deb file onto a USB and transferred it and tried installing it from there.

It pops up with a window saying

```
dependency is not satisfiable: python central(>=0.6.11)
```

And I'm not exactly sure what that means. I am assuming python is not up to date for the program to work properly?

EDIT: The machine can not connect to the Internet.

EDIT:
I think I've hunted down at least some of the dependencies. But now when I try to install python 2.7 it says Breaks existing package.

What does that mean?

Comment: Why aren't you just connecting to the internet and installing the package? You are down to the rabbit hole with that software.

Answer (score 4):

You assume correctly :-)

Your package manager is complaining that the package you're trying to install is requesting that `python-central` with a version greater than or equal to 0.6.11 is installed, but it can't install it.

You have two problems here - the first is that you're not connected to the internet and the second is the fact that `python-central` is depreciated ([read it here](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/TransitionToDHPython2?action=show&redirect=Python%2FPythonSupportToDHPython2))

Generally, you can get around the first issue by using `apt-offline`, which you can read about [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT).

The second issue is a bigger problem.  The developer of the package you initally tried to install will need to update the package to use the replacement for `python-central`.  Of course, they may have done this already - but you've downloaded the wrong version.  Check the source website again and make sure you've downloaded the correct version.

Comment: So I am looking at the site here(http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/compizconfig-settings-manager) I clicked on all. Should I have chose a different one?

Comment: That is for Ubuntu Precise (v12.04). First, confirm which version you're using by typing `cat /etc/os-release | grep VERSION=`.  Then fetch the correct version from packages.ubuntu.com.  For example, if you're using the latest (v14.04) verion of Ubuntu, simply change `precise` to `trusty` in your URL above.  As @ams mentions below, they will probably be more dependencies afterwards.

Comment: ah yes I am using 14.04 so your example helped haha

Comment: I think I've hunted down atleast some of the dependencies. But now when I try to install python 2.7 it says Breaks existing package. What does that mean

Comment: Some packages are mutually exclusive - you can have one or the other, but not both.  It sounds like `python 2.7` isn't happy to be installed with something (which you haven't stated).  It could be simply a small package that also needs updating or it could be huge.  Considering you're new to Ubuntu, you're not doing yourself any favours by installing things this way.  Can you not get the system on the Internet to install the packages?  It will be much easier in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

It means `python central` is not installed, or too old.

You need to connect to the internet, or go chase the dependencies manually. There'll probably be more after this one.

Answer (score 1):

This is telling you that a dependancy (another package that is required to run the one you want to install) is either not installed on the system, or that the version installed is too old.

The easiest way to make that work is to connect the machine to the internet and install with the package manager. This will automatically get and install any dependancies for you.

Answer (score 0):

The message `"Dependency is not satisfiable: python-central(>=0.6.11)"` means that you also need to install the `python-central` package, at version 0.6.11 as a minimum.

However, since you are working on an offline computer, is very likely that you will run into another missing dependencies problem.

You can check several methods to download and install packages without an internet connection in the answers to [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

By the way, which Ubuntu release are you using? The last release that included `python-central` was 13.10 (saucy), and compizconfig-settings-manager didn't require it after 12.10 LTS (precise)

Comment: Yes I just realized I downloaded it for 12.04 not 14.04 like I am using. I did not know the names of each version so I had no idea.